# Different measure results using GoogleMap and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**Different measure results using same distance with GoogleMap and MongoDB**
In fact this question is pretty difficult to respond. Because MongoDB's and GoogleMap's methods are needed to solve this issue. And some calculates. According to my other tests, distance difference among them can be changes on different locations on the Earth. In my case this situation is not important. But this is a problem...

---

I have two points coordinates that are `[41.034892, 28.980788]` and `[41.036770, 28.985557]`. Using GoogleMaps that two point's distance is measured as 452 meters. But using MongoDB `$near` and `$maxDistance` operators I can reach from one point to another at 562 meters.

The difference is 110 meters. Does anyone know the reason?

A sample doc is the below;

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54ddd5a06c0213711ca59257"),
    "loc": { "type":"Point", "coordinates":[41.034892, 28.980788] }
}
```

And used query phrase is the below;

```
{
    'loc': {
        $near: {
            $geometry: { "type":"Point", "coordinates":[41.036770, 28.985557] } ,
            $maxDistance: 562                           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably switched the longitude and latitude coordinates: either when calculating distance on Google Maps or you switched the order of coordinates in your Point objects in MongoDB.

GeoJSON standard for [Point geometry object](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id2) states that the first item in the array is longitude and second one is latitude.

If you try to calculate the distance between Lat 28.980788, Long 41.034892 and Lat 28.985557, Long 41.036770 using Google Maps you will get the same result as from MongoDB.

Quick check on [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) gave me the distance of 0.5609 km (560.9m).

**Edit**

From your comment I suspect that you probably created your Points with the wrong coordinates array. This should be your sample document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54ddd5a06c0213711ca59257"),
    "loc": { "type":"Point", "coordinates":[28.980788, 41.034892] }
}
```